# Filtering pivot table data with Laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, filtering, eloquent, pivot-table

Let's say I have three tables (this is just an example):

```
users
   user_id
   username

roles
   role_id
   name

user_roles
    user_id
    role_id
    primary (boolean)
```

And the corresponding laravel models:

```
   class User extends Eloquent {
        public function roles() {
              return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withPivot('primary');
        }
   }
   class Role extends Eloquent {
         public function users() {
              return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('primary');
         }
   }
```

I want to get a list of all users, but with only the primary roles in the returned object.
If I use something like:

```
$users = User::with('roles')->find(1);
```

Each user object will have a list of all the roles corresponding to it. I want this list to contain only the primary roles. Is there any way to do this from a query, without post processing the $users array?

Comment: Are you trying to query one user's roles or many users' roles?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538527/how-to-filter-a-pivot-table-using-eloquent

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$users = User::with(array('roles' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('primary', 1); 
}))->find(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use this solution.

Comment: WARNING: I tried this in Laravel 7.x (although not precisely analysed) and this query also returned users where the column should not be matched!, Something's weird here : the actual SQL query constructed and executed by laravel ends with: "... where pivot_table.user_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) and pivot_extra_column = 1" so it actually returns all 7 users (I do not know what for), even those that do not have pivot_extra_column = 1. So this is weird! Perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 19):

I'd suggest you create an extra method in your User model like this:

```
public function primaryRoles() {
    return $this->roles()->wherePivot('primary', true);
}
```

Then use something like:

```
$users = User::with('primaryRoles')->find(1);
```

Also, the "Eager Load Constraints" section in [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I like your solution, however I'm on Laravel 4.0, so I can't use wherePivot.

Comment: @user1544110 thanks! For Laravel 4.0 you can use a where() instead of the wherePivot()

Comment: but if you use where instead of wherePivot then the query would check if table roles has a column primary?