# Laravel/Eloquent: condition on a pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have 3 tables 'users', 'teams' and 'teams_users' (a pivot table). The pivot table contains a boolean field 'kicked'. I didn't find the way to get the list of teams which the user has not been kicked from. My code looks like this:

```
$teams = Team::withCount('users')
               ->where($params)
               ->orderBy(DB::raw('users_count / max_members'), 'desc')
               ->orderBy('team_id', 'desc')
               ->has('users', '<', DB::raw('max_members'));

$user = app('auth')->user();
if (isset($user)) {
    // Here add the condition to exclude teams the user has been kicked from
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering pivot table data with Laravel models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759891/filtering-pivot-table-data-with-laravel-models)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Digging the documentation, I found this:

```
if (isset($user)) {
    $teams->whereDoesntHave('users', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where("is_kicked", "=", '1')
              ->where('teams_users.user_id', '=', $user->id);
    });
}
```

It generates a 'NOT EXISTS' condition in the SQL query.
Works perfectly!

Comment: Why the DB::raw?

Comment: @NathanHeffley Indeed it is useless

Comment: if this solved your problem, even though it's your own answer you should accept it. Help out the people who stumble across this in the future a little bit.

Answer (score 5):

To start off, by convention your pivot should be named team_user and have team_id and user_id columns (it can have extras as well of course).

Next you should set up your relationships inside the models if you haven't yet. Use the `belongsToMany()` relationship inside your User model to be able to fetch teams like this

`$user->teams`

then you can simply do this

`$user->teams()->where('kicked', false)->get()`

more detail on relationships here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships (see Many to Many for pivot table)

Comment: Thank you, you put me on the right path. Actually, I used `$teams->whereDoesntHave('users', function ($query){});` which filters my query the way I want.