# Filter pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to add a `where` clause on one of the tables of the `pivot table` inside the `pivot table` ? For example in the code below, how can i add a `where` clause in `products_categories` to specify the `products` with `type='ELECTRONICS'` ?

```
DB::table("products_categories")
    ->whereIn("category_id", array_values($ids))
    ->pluck("id")
    ->all();
```

Comment: This post could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538527/how-to-filter-a-pivot-table-using-eloquent

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$type = "ELECTRONICS";
$products_categories = Product::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($type){
    $q->where('type', "%$type%");
})->get();
```